# How to check if a JsonNode object in jackson can be mapped to an PoJo object?

Tags: java, jackson

Iam reading a jsonfile from a file and check wether it can be converted to a POJO class using jackson api.
rightnow iam reading file mapping it to a JsonNode and trying to check wether the jsonNode can be converted to a POJO class.
Is there any alternate way to do this.

```
    byte[] jsonData = Files.readAllBytes(Paths.get("filepath"));
    JsonNode jsonNode = mapper.readTree(jsonData);
    GerritJsonParser gerparse=new GerritJsonParser();
```

Is there any method that returns boolean that checks if Json Node can be converted to a POJO
for eg like

```
     canConvert(jsonData,gerparse.class);
```

Comment: Don't judge by yourself, if you can't resolve to an object, it will throw an exception.

Comment: yeah actually i want to compare to many kinds of json classes that i built and check which one the input file matches which cant be done by throwing an exception